# Elasticsearch Mapping Template

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

ELK Stack version 6.2.1

I am following this tutorial and trying to send tshark captures to ELK.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/analyzing-network-packets-with-wireshark-elasticsearch-and-kibana

As tshark captures all fields as text, I am trying to create a mapping in elasticsearch to ensure number fields are indexed as integer, text as string etc...

I am therefore required to create an elasticsearch mapping but am confused as to what this is. Does this mean to create an index template like below

packets-index_pattern.json   with the following entry

```
PUT _template/packets
{
  "template": "packets-*",
  "mappings": {
    "pcap_file": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "layers": {
          "properties": {
            "frame": {
              "properties": {
                "frame_frame_len": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "frame_frame_protocols": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "ip": {
              "properties": {
                "ip_ip_src": {
                  "type": "ip"
                },
                "ip_ip_dst": {
                  "type": "ip"
                }
              }
            },
            "udp": {
              "properties": {
                "udp_udp_srcport": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "udp_udp_dstport": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So far I have created a file called packets-index_pattern.json and tried to upload it to Elasticsearch using the below, however I get an error saying status 400 curl: (6) could not resolve host: Content-Type

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_template/packets-?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Any help glady accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header that you are inserting before the json:

```
PUT _template/packets
```

it is the kibana notation for specify the verb (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE) and the endpoint of a request.

If you are using curl, you have to remove it from your packets-index_pattern.json file.

Comment: thanks Dario ! I will give that a bash and report back ! Thanks again my friend !

Answer (score 1):

TShark now supports the `-G elastic-mapping` option.
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/relnotes/wireshark-3.0.0.html